# .htaccess и nginx

Tags: php, nginx, веб-сайт

Перевел сервер на nginx. Как мне "Перенести" эти правила в nginx? Я полагаю мне нужно обновлять конфиг nginx?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 404 /.(svn|git|hg|bzr|cvs)|dump.sql(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (dfiles/.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dfiles.php?request=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(jscss/.*)!(img/.*)!(image.php.*)!(video.php.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?rad_pr=1&request=$1
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот базовый конфиг для связки NGINX + PHP, не забудьте установить **PHP-FPM**!

```
server {
  # Example PHP Nginx FPM config file
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  root /var/www/html;

  # Add index.php to setup Nginx, PHP & PHP-FPM config
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name _;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # pass PHP scripts on Nginx to FastCGI (PHP-FPM) server
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # Nginx php-fpm sock config:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    # Nginx php-cgi config :
    # Nginx PHP fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  # deny access to Apache .htaccess on Nginx with PHP, 
  # if Apache and Nginx document roots concur
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
} # End of PHP FPM Nginx config example
```

Comment: В вопросе спрашивали про конкретно «эти правила», а не про «базовый конфиг»

Comment: Так возьмите базовый конфиг и перепишите под нужные вам правила

Comment: Ну так именно об этом и вопрос — как переписать?

Comment: Да. Базовый конфиг я уже настроил, сайт работает, но для его полноценной работы мне необходимо перенести эти правила. Пытался воспользоваться конвертером, но так понял это мертвая тема. С nginx до этого не особо сталкивался, прошу простить.